# Is it possible to change the widthSegments parameter (from SphereGeometry) over time?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Using Three.JS I have the following Sphere Geometry:

```
        var radius = 1 ;
        var widthSegments = 12;
        var heightSegments = 12;

        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius, widthSegments, heightSegments);
        const material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
            color: 'white',
            size: 0.01, 
        });
```

I would like its property, `widthSegments`, to change as a function of time. So I tried creating the following function:

```
  var ChangeWidth = function (){
        var time = Date.now() * 0.0005;
        widthSegments =  Math.sin(time * 0.7) * 30;
    }
```

And then added it to my `update` function

```
   function update() 
        {
            requestAnimationFrame( update );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
            animate();    
            ChangeWidth();
        }
```

But well, noting has actually changed. Is it possible to change `widthSegments` and consequently the variable `geometry`?

*EDIT*

New function to delete and recreate the geometry with a new `widthSegments` value

```
function update() {
            scene.add(points);
            requestAnimationFrame( update );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
            }
        update();

        while (widthSegments < 60){

        // I begin the loop by destroying the older geometry
        var DestroyGeometry = function() {
            scene.remove(points);
            points.geometry.dispose();
        }

        DestroyGeometry();    

        // Then, I create a new geometry
        const newGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( radius, widthSegments, heightSegments );
        points = new THREE.Points( newGeometry, material );

        // Making sure the widthSegments is going to be increase
        widthSegments += 0.5; 

        // I end creating a new function to render the NewGeometry
        var Recreate = function() {
            scene.add(points);
            requestAnimationFrame( update );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }

        Recreate();
        }
```

But this is clearly not working. Both `DestroyGeometry()` and `Recreate()` functions have no effect at all. I wonder if they can be placed inside a `while` loop.

Comment: BTW: `widthSegments` represents  a value (no reference!) passed to the ctor of `SphereGeometry`. Changing the value of `widthSegments` over time would have no effect in any event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to change widthSegments and consequently the variable geometry?

No, the parameters of all geometry generators are only evaluated when the geometry is constructed. If you want to change parameters over time, you have to remove the old geometry and create a new one. Something like:

```js
scene.remove( points );
points.geometry.dispose(); // free internal buffers

const newGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry( radius, widthSegments, heightSegments );
points = new THREE.Points( newGeometry, material ); // create new point cloud with new geometry and existing material
scene.add( points );
```

Comment: So, in theory, I should be able to create a while loop to destroy and recreate the geometry with said new parameter, correct? I think I made it work but the loop is to fast and I need to slow it down somehow. I tried some asyc and await but I failed. I edited the original post with my new function.

Comment: Your approach is not the right way for this kind of animation. I suggest you study how morph-target animation works.